# In MFC how to display list box on the BCN_DROPDOWN event of split button control

Tags: mfc

I am using VS2008.

I have MFC dialog based application with split button control.

I want to display a list box on the BCN_DROPDOWN event of split button control. I dont know how to achieve it?

Comment: Either create a list box control in your button control handler, or show the list box, if it already exists. What are you having difficulty with?

Comment: On a second thought, what problem are you *really* trying to solve, for which your proposed solution is to re-implement the split button functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Reference to the documentation of the CSplitButton class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514109.aspx

If you want to change default behaviour then use the override:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMySplitButton,
    CSplitButton)  
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(BCN_DROPDOWN, &CMySplitButton::OnDropDown)  
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

(...)

```
afx_msg void OnDropDown(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult);
```

You can in this function show your listbox or whatever you like.

If the listbox you refer to the actual submenu (3) as shown in the documentation, then add a menu: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b6tafew.aspx and set the resource ID for that menu into SetDropDownMenu() function

```
void SetDropDownMenu(
    UINT nMenuId,   
    UINT nSubMenuId);
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score -1):

1. You must add your menu into a resource.
   Ex:IDR_MENU_BUTTON_ANY
2. Declare some Resource symbols for submenu. It will change *.rc and resource.h.

Your resource will look like:

```js
IDR_MENU_BUTTON_ANY
BEGIN
    POPUP "SampleMenu"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "Sub1",                        ID_SUB_MENU_1
        MENUITEM "Sub2",                        ID_SUB_MENU_2
    END
END
```

When you initialize your dialog. You should insert some code as below:

```js
//Your split button
CMFCSplitButton m_btnAny;

//Set dropdown menu
m_btnAny.SetDropDownMenu(IDR_MENU_BUTTON_ANY, 0);
```

More, I found the following link. The author provided an example. It may help you.
http://codexpert.ro/blog/2013/02/01/split-button-control/#comment-22983